# How add C3 charts to angular 2+ project

Tags: angular, charts, c3.js

I searched a lot about Angular2 chart packages but there was no name of C3.js till I found an example of C3.js charts in link below
[ani-angular.strapui.com/dashboard/charts/c3-chart](http://ani-angular.strapui.com/dashboard/charts/c3-chart)

Then I searched for "C3 charts for angular" founded results was all about AngularJS projects. Even on their [website](http://c3js.org/) was no guide to how to setup this package for angular

I'm sure there is a way that you can add C3 chart to angular2+ project. Is there anyone that know how you do this?

Comment: You can also try to use this https://github.com/jsHurdle/ng2-c3

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> There wasn't an answer on stackoverflow so I answer it by my self

1- run this command in your project root:

```
npm install c3
npm install @types/c3
```

2- add `"../node_modules/c3/c3.min.css",` to **.angular-cli.json** => style section

(In angular 6+ add `@import "../node_modules/c3/c3.min.css";` to **styles.css**)

3- add  `<div id="chart"></div>` to your component template

4- add `import * as c3 from 'c3';` to your component

5- add bellow codes to your typescript

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
        data: {
            columns: [
                ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
            ]
        }
    });
}
```

I hope will it be helpful for you, comment if there was any problem

Comment: Can you can send a link of exact thing that you want ? @arun-bertil

Comment: I mean c3.generate but I need c3.Sankey.Butterfly to work in Angular 4

Comment: Also the javascript used in C3 for Angular 1 was cofeescript

Comment: Hello , how can i generate chart in *ngFor ?

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a package bundling c3 that can avoid having this warning when migrating to Angular 10 (is that even possible?)

WARNING in financial-figure.js depends on 'c3'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.