# How to integrate C3 Gauge Chart into Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, c3.js

I am trying to integrate C3 Gauge Chart: http://c3js.org/samples/chart_gauge.html  to a fresh Angular 5 application.

Here is my code chart.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as c3 from 'c3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.css']
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
        data: {
            columns: [
                ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
            ]
        }
    });
  }

}
```

Here is my chart.component.html

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

But I am getting the following error.

[image]

Following  what's in here didn't solve my problem: [How add C3 charts to angular 2+ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250941/how-add-c3-charts-to-angular-2-project)

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you **angular-cli.json** add the following:

```
scripts: [
   "/path/to/d3.v4.min.js",
   "/path/to/c3.min.js"
]
```

Apparently, `c3.js` library depends on the `d3.js` library, but recent versions of `c3.js` library now depend on the version 4 of `d3.js`.

So, make sure you have that version of `d3.js` before attemtping to use `c3.js`.

In the [Github repository](https://github.com/c3js/c3) you'll find this:

Dependency:

- D3.js ^4.12.0

**Update:**

As an alternative, @BadisMerabet found a workaround downgrading the library. If you already have functionality that depend on an older version of `d3.js`, this can be a good short-time solution.

```
npm install --save c3@0.4.22
```

Comment: I didn't add anything to scripts. Upgrading d3 to version 4 fixed my issue. thanks !

Comment: @BadisMerabet great! I'm glad! Have fun with `c3.js`! :D

Comment: Now my ng2-nvd3 charts are broken :) as they are dependent to d3 v3 : https://github.com/krispo/ng2-nvd3 . I will see if I will create another issue.

Comment: Just use directly the library instead of a package if you're having issues with that package. Or open a new issue and let's see how to resolve that one! :D

Comment: I have used a downgraded version of C3

Comment: @BadisMerabet Nice! That's also a good solution. If you want, and with your permission, I would add it to my answer, so people with the same issue find all the solutions in the same place. Is it ok for you?

Answer (score 1):

I have run: `npm install --save c3@0.4.22` to fix my issue as I am already using d3 version 3.

Latest versions of C3 use D3 version 4.